# Is there a way to find out the SDK version installed on my server?

Tags: rally

How can i find out which SDK is being used on my Rally server?
I'm trying to use 2.0p4 but i get a script error mentioning `Rally` object is undefined.

i checked previous post on SO and found out the App syntax was different in SDK 1.0 where `Rally` object was not mentioned.

can it be that my Rally server is not supporting SDK 2.0p4 APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently rally1.rallydev.com is running the latest preview, 2.0p4.
All SDK versions are located at [server]/apps/[version].

For SDK 1 the latest is here:
[server]/apps/1.32/sdk.js (or sdk.js?debug=true)

For SDK 2 preview the latest is here:
[server]/apps/2.0p4/sdk.js (or sdk-debug.js)

If you are running an on prem version of Rally you'll have to just experiment and see what the most recent versions are you have.